# css - font size relative to overridden value

Tags: css, less, font-size

I know that `em` will set the `font-size` relative to the parent.  What if I wanted to set the font-size relative to the overridden value of a given element?

For instance:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.smaller h1 {
    font-size: (80 percent of the standard h1);
}
```

Is this possible?

I should mention that I'm using `less` which might provide some more flexibility.

Comment: `em` doesn't work with the cascade so you can't really do this with an `em` value.

Comment: Right, that's the question.

Comment: There is no way to do this with pure CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about EMs, I suppose you could try it and see what happens.

If you wanted to utilize less's variables, you could do something like this:

```
@h1-font-size: 20px;
h1 { 
    font-size: @h1-font-size;
}

.smaller h1 {
    font-size: @h1-font-size * .8;
}
```

Comment: Thanks cjd, actually that's how I've ended up doing it unless there's a better alternative.  It's a bit tedious, making a variable for all of the elements that I'd like to make smaller.

Comment: You can define one base font size variable for all of your less files, then you can just multiply that to get your heading font sizes so you don't need to always create a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. There is no way to make anything relative to the “overridden value”. You should design your styling in a different way.

And it would be rather odd to set heading size as a fixed amount of pixels for some headings and as relative to an “overriden value”, which is generally unknown and should be expected to be browser-dependent.

But to the extent that you expect browsers to have common defaults, you can pretty much use the HTML5 [“expected rendering” rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendering), since they reflect usual browser practice rather well. According to them, `h1` has `font-size: 2.00em`, so if you wish to set some size to 80% of that, just use `1.6em`.